# How to upload pdf or jpeg file?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have the following 3 javascript routines:

```
function readFile(file, onLoadCallback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
    alert(file.name);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```
function processfile(filename, filecontent) {
    //finish working here
    PageMethods.setFile(filename, filecontent);
}
```

```
$('#div').on(
    'drop',
    function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer) {
            if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
                    const file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i];
                    readFile(file, function (e2) {
                        processfile(file.name, e2.target.result);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to upload docx-files, xlsx-files and txt-files - and everything works very fine. But when I try to upload pdf and jpeg files - nothing happens :-(

So therefore I ask how to upload these filetypes with this routine.

Best regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: The file was to big to transfer to PageMethods - so therefore I have incremented jsonSerialization maxJsonLength in my webconfig.

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```